dynamically load and conditionally show component in Angular
In my Angular App, I have a router outlet and on the side, I have some preview container boxes showing preview components where the corresponding main component is routed to and shown in the router outlet on clicking on those boxes while the previous main component is then loaded into the now free preview container.
Basically, it's working as intended but I do have one special case when I click the invite Family Member Button, then the #leftThirdContainer should appear in the view(*ngIf is used for that) with the corresponding preview component shown in the leftThirdContainer. I do this by using an Observable that checks the current route and whenever it matches '/private/invite' it shall be true. But it seems that even when I wait for the router event to fire the leftThirdContainer is undefined and therefore the component doesn't show in the view. Only on refresh, the component is then shown correctly in the leftThirdContainer.
here is my html:
<button mat-flat-button color="primary" (click)="inviteFamilyMember()" class="invite-button" *ngIf="!(showThirdPreviewContainer$ | async)">invite</button>
<div class="container">
  <div class="column column-1">
    <div class="row row-1" (click)="loadComponents('leftFirst')">
      <ng-container #leftFirstContainer></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-2" (click)="loadComponents('leftSecond')">
      <ng-container #leftSecondContainer></ng-container>
    </div>
    <div class="row row-3" (click)="loadComponents('leftThird')" *ngIf="showThirdPreviewContainer$ | async">
      <ng-container #leftThirdContainer></ng-container>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column column-2">
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>

and here the typescript class:
export class PrivateComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('leftFirstContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) leftFirstContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('leftSecondContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) leftSecondContainer: ViewContainerRef;
  @ViewChild('leftThirdContainer', { read: ViewContainerRef }) leftThirdContainer: ViewContainerRef;

  showThirdPreviewContainer$: Observable<boolean>;

  private destroyRef = inject(DestroyRef);

  constructor(
    private privateComponentService: PrivateComponentSerivce,
    private router: Router,
    ) {
    this.showThirdPreviewContainer$ = this.router.events.pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart || event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map((event: NavigationStart | NavigationEnd) => event.url === '/private/invite'),
      startWith(this.router.url === '/private/invite'),
      takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)
    );
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.privateComponentService.getRefreshTriggered()) {
      this.privateComponentService.setRefreshTriggered(false);
      this.loadPreviewComponents(false);
    } else {
      this.initComponentContainer()
    }
  }

  loadComponents(containerType: ContainerTypes): void {
    const currentComponentContainer = this.privateComponentService.getCurrentComponentContainer();
    const newComponentContainer = this.privateComponentService.mapContainerComponents(containerType, currentComponentContainer);

    if(newComponentContainer?.main) {
      this.router.navigate([newComponentContainer.main]).then(() => this.setPreviewComponents(newComponentContainer));
    }
  }

  inviteFamilyMember(): void {
    this.router.navigate([MainContainerRoutes.Invite]).then(() => {
      this.router.events.pipe(
        filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
        takeUntilDestroyed(this.destroyRef)
      ).subscribe((event) => {
        this.loadPreviewComponents(true);
      });
    });
  }

  private initComponentContainer() {
    const currentComponentContainer = this.privateComponentService.getCurrentComponentContainer();
    this.router.navigate([currentComponentContainer.main]).then(() => this.setPreviewComponents(currentComponentContainer));
  }

  private loadPreviewComponents(privateInviteClicked: boolean) {
    const currentComponentContainer = this.privateComponentService.getCurrentComponentContainer();
    if(privateInviteClicked) {
      const newComponentContainer = this.privateComponentService.mapContainerForInviteComponent(currentComponentContainer);
      this.setPreviewComponents(newComponentContainer);
    } else {
      this.setPreviewComponents(currentComponentContainer);
    }
  }

  private setPreviewComponents(componentContainer: ContainerComponents) {
    if (this.leftFirstContainer) this.leftFirstContainer.clear();
    if (this.leftSecondContainer) this.leftSecondContainer.clear();
    if (this.leftThirdContainer) this.leftThirdContainer.clear();

    if(componentContainer?.leftFirst && componentContainer?.leftSecond && this.leftFirstContainer && this.leftSecondContainer) {
      const leftFirstComponentRef = this.leftFirstContainer.createComponent(COMPONENTS[componentContainer.leftFirst]);
      const leftSecondComponentRef = this.leftSecondContainer.createComponent(COMPONENTS[componentContainer.leftSecond]);
      if(this.leftThirdContainer && componentContainer?.leftThird) {
        const leftThirdComponentRef = this.leftThirdContainer.createComponent(COMPONENTS[componentContainer.leftThird]);
      }
      this.privateComponentService.setCurrentComponentContainer(componentContainer);
    }
  }
}

I know I could wait for the component to be loaded using setTimeout(that would work) but that doesn't seem right. So I want to know if there is something wrong with my code and understanding of Angular, and why it doesn't work as intended. Or is there another Angular way of achieving what I want (dynamically load and conditionally show components)?

I'm developing in angular regularly and can show how I would solve it. Working with @ViewChild can be necessary in some cases but from first sight I don't see the need here. Tell me when I'm wrong!
I can't tell why it doesn't work. You can create a stackblitz so I can dive deeper in it - if you want to stick to your current implementation.
My approach is a bit different, a more "native" way of angular, without the ViewChild thing.
Here is my pseudo code. Note: I like to use the new conditional-template-statements like @if. (It's just syntactic sugar. You can the widely used *ngIf="something" directive as well.)
parent-component.ts
export class ParentComponent {
  protected showThirdPreviewContainer$: Observable<boolean> = of(true).pipe();
  protected container: Map = {
    leftFirst: undefined,
    leftSecond: undefined,
    leftThird: undefined,
  };

  private privateComponentService = inject(PrivateComponentService);

  loadComponents(containerKey: string): void {
    this.container[containerKey] =
      this.privateComponentService.getCurrentComponentContainer(containerKey);
  }
}

parent-component.html
 <!-- ✅ list all boxes her, and put dynamic loader in them -->
    @if(container['leftFirst']; as leftFirst) {
      <div><b>click again!</b></div>
      <!-- ✅ here the magic happens! -->
      <div>
        loaded:
        <app-dynamic-loader [type]="leftFirst"></app-dynamic-loader>
      </div>
      } @else { click me for random component }
    </div>
    <div
      class="row row-2"
      (click)="loadComponents('leftSecond')"
      style="width:150px;height:100px;background-color:lightblue;"
    >
      @if(container['leftSecond']; as leftSecond) {
      <div><b>click again!</b></div>
      <div>
        loaded:
        <app-dynamic-loader [type]="leftSecond"></app-dynamic-loader>
      </div>
      } @else { click me for random component }
    </div>
    <!-- etc. -->

dynamic-container.component.ts
export class DynamicComponent { // ✅ <-- this does the job!
    @Input
    type: ContainerType;
}

dynamic-loader.component.html
@if(typeStr() === "ComponentA") {
<app-component-a></app-component-a>
} @else if(typeStr() === "ComponentB") {
<app-component-b></app-component-b>
} @else if(typeStr() === "ComponentC") {
<app-component-c></app-component-c>
} @else if(typeStr() === "ComponentD") {
<app-component-d></app-component-d>
} @else if(typeStr() === "ComponentE") {
<app-component-e></app-component-e>
} @else {
<p style="color:red;">invalid component-type: {{ typeStr() }}</p>
}

If my answer is what you are looking for I would love if you accept it. If not, let me know.
Stackblitz Demo (it's fun!)

thanks for the idea, i changed it to a simple parent child component and conditionally showing the components.
But still i wanted to know why my viewref stays undefined when i try to create the component, just for my understanding of Angular and what is happening here in the background.

"Or is there another Angular way of achieving what I want (dynamically load and conditionally show components)?". That's what my answer does.

yes you are right about that. i guess i accept your answer and thank you for your efforts.
